# Best practice for contextual or state based overrides of child components

Tags: sass

I have my stylesheets broken out to represent individual components (nav, nav-item, etc). I'm trying to understand the best way to allow a parent to override child style based on it's state or context (change the nav-item when the nav is open, change the nav when it's on the homepage, etc).

Say for example I have a nav that contains nav-items. These are seperated into their own stylesheets nav.scss and nav-item.scss. When the .nav component has the .open class added I want to make the .nav-item background turn red. I could do that like this:

```
/* nav.scss */
@import nav-item.scss
.nav{
    &.open{
        .nav-item{
            background: red;
        }
    }
}

 /* nav-item.scss */
.nav-item{
    background: blue;
}
```

This works fine, but now styles that are applied to .nav-item are being applied outside of the .nav-item stylesheet, if this is happening in multiple locations it could make it very difficult to track down which file is adding which styles to the .nav-item. An alternative is this:

```
 /* nav.scss */
@import nav-item.scss
.nav{

}

 /* nav-item.scss */
.nav-item{
    background: blue;
    .nav.open &{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

This syntax allows me to reach up the parent tree and see if I'm nested within .nav.open then apply the red background. This is great because all of nav-items styles are now contained in the same file making it easier to see all possibilities. However, I'm still referencing an outside class which seems wrong, plus if I have a lot of variants this file could quickly get nasty:

```
 /* nav-item.scss */
.nav-item{
    background: blue;
    .nav.open &{
        background: red;
    }
    .nav.sticky.open &{
        background: blue;
    }
    .homepage .nav.open &{
        @media screen and (max-width: $break-small) {
             background: green;
         }
    }
}
```

We could try using mixins:

```
 /* nav.scss */
@import nav-item.scss
.nav{
    &.open{
        @include navItemRedWide();
    }
}

 /* nav-item.scss */
.nav-item{
    background: blue;
}
@mixin navItemRedWide() {
    .nav-item {
        background: red;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

This effectively allows nav-item.scss to contain all of it's own styles, and lets .nav dictate which styles to apply without being able to directly add/modify style properties on the class. This seems better than the other solution but could result is a lot of mixins and possible a lot of duplicate code if I have to repeat the nesting in every mixin:

```
 /* nav-item.scss */
@mixin navItemLargeIcon() {
    .nav-item {
       .inner{
           .icon{
                font-size: 4rem;
           }       
       }
    }
}
@mixin navItemSmallIcon() {
    .nav-item {
       .inner{
           .icon{
                font-size: 1rem;
           }       
       }
    }
}
```

Finally, this issue is compounded if I there is a child of a child component that you would need to pull mixins from:

```
 /* nav.scss */
@import nav-panel.scss
@import nav-item.scss
.nav{
    &.open{
        @include navItemRed();
        @include navPanelRed();
    }
}

 /* nav-panel.scss */
@import nav-item.scss
.nav-panel{
    background: blue;
    &.collapse{
       @include navPanelBlue();
    }
}
@mixin navPanelRed() {
    .nav-panel {
        background: red;
    }
}

 /* nav-item.scss */
.nav-item{
    background: blue;
}
@mixin navItemRed() {
    .nav-item {
        background: red;
    }
}
@mixin navItemBlue() {
    .nav-item {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Now I have root files importing children of children just to apply their mixin while the middle child is also importing the child and potentially applying overriding mixins and the while thing just becomes and unmaintainable mess.

What is the best practice for applying these sort of context or state based styling and overrides of child components?

Answer (score 1):

As you describe there are a lot of ways to handle context in SCSS but if I have to pick one it would be **mixin based**

```
//  -----------------------------
//  _nav.scss
//  -----------------------------
//  Base styling
@mixin nav {
    .nav {
        ...
    }
}

//  Context overrides/add-ons
//  note! keep context overrides in the component scss - it makes 
//  it easier to track and provides an overview of variations 
@mixin nav-context-1 { .context-1 .nav { ... } }
@mixin nav-context-2 { .context-2 .nav { ... } }
@mixin nav-context-3 { .context-3 .nav { ... } }
```

Using mixins (for everything) makes it predictable what is printed in your final CSS as your compiling style.scss will only contain imports and includes (assemble)

```
//  -----------------------------
//  style.scss
//  -----------------------------
//  Imports
@import 
    '_reset.scss',
    '_typography.scss',
    '_nav.scss',
    ...
;


//  Assemble 
@include reset: 
@include typography;

@include nav;
@include nav-context-1;
@include nav-context-2;
//  @include nav-context-3;     we didn't need this anyway
```

Again there is no one answer – but the above is the one I found the most structured and easy to handle.

**PS.** A little twist to the above could be to make the context mixins depend on nav as a wrapping include. This way Sass will throw an error if you try to include an override without the base being present

```
@mixin nav {
    .nav {
        ...
        @content; //  contexts will go here
    }
}

//  note! we use & in the selector to disallow include at root level
@mixin nav-context-1 { .context-1 & { ... } }
@mixin nav-context-2 { .context-2 & { ... } }
@mixin nav-context-3 { .context-3 & { ... } }


//  Assemble
@include nav {
    @include nav-context-1;
    @include nav-context-2;
    @include nav-context-3;
}

@include nav-context-3;  // this will throw an error
```